# how do I reference the active rows from a specified number of columns in a create calendar event in script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create events in a calendar from a google spreadsheet.
I need the script to reference only the first 6 columns of the sheet and only the cells containing data within them

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A8:G11");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
var headerRows = 0;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();
```

[Operations sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16xdJxni5D7_860z0R4yUtB8Vlhk7eesiLAnI3RE75oE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: 1. Mentioning a user that didn't post a comment yet will not throw a notification. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: 2. The code isn't complete. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: 3. Take a look to the [getActiveRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange) method documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With a little help i have everything working nicely.
Rather than updating every cell, I just loop through the cells that hold the event ID and update those.
Here is the complete code. Thanks To the community for helping me out with this one.

```
function onOpen() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var entries = [{
name : "Export Events",
functionName : "exportEvents"
}];
sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
* Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
*/
function exportEvents() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var headerRows = 6;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getDisplayValues();
// var calId = "your cal id"; // PRODUCTION
var calId = "your cal id"; // TEST
Logger.log("length");
Logger.log(data.length);
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
var row    = data[i];
var date   = new Date(row[0]);  // First column
var title  = row[1];           // Second column
var tstart = new Date(row[2]);
tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
var tstop = new Date(row[3]);
tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
var loc  = row[4];
var desc = row[5];
var id   = row[6];              // Sixth column == eventId
// Check if event already exists, update it if it does
Logger.log("+++++++++++++++++++++")
Logger.log(id.length);
if (id.length > 0) {
  try {
    var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
  }
  catch (e) {
    // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event     doesn't exist
  } 
}
if (!event) {
  //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new   Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
  var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
  var r = i + 1;
  var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + r);
  cell.setValue(newEvent);
}
else {
  event.setTitle(title);
  event.setDescription(desc);
  event.setLocation(loc);
  // event.setTime(tstart, tstop); // cannot setTime on eventSeries.
  // ... but we CAN set recurrence!
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
}
debugger;
```

}
}